# Angular js inline expression and condition

Tags: html, angularjs, expression, conditional-statements

How to write multiple `html` inline expression and condition.

**Situation**

`{{step}}` value should change based on condition while scrolling

My controller

```
controller(){
 $scope.step = 1;
  $scope.sectionOneValue   = 100;
  $scope.sectionTwoValue   = 200;
  $scope.sectionThreeValue = 300;

 scroll function(){
   $scope.scrollValue =  chaningValue
 }
}
```

**Inline angular expression and condition**

```
if scrollValue  > sectionOneValue 
   step = 1;
if scrollValue  > sectionTwoValue 
   step = 2;
if scrollValue  > sectionThreeValue 
   step = 3;
```

**I am targeting here**

```
{{ step | angular expression and condition }}
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want. But you can just change the value of step in the controller every time you change the value of scrollValue. Or use a function that returns the right step value based on the current value of scrollValue.

Comment: Any possibility to write inline multiple expression and condition ?

Comment: That is too vague to be answered. But anyway, JavaScript code belongs to the controller (or services). Not to the view. The whole point of the controller is to provide functions and values that are callable/usable from the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to extract all work with data to controller.

**Example:**

In controller:

```
$scope.getStep = function(scrollValue) {
    if (scrollValue > sectionOneValue) {
        return 1;
    } else if (scrollValue > sectionTwoValue) {
        return 2;
    } else if (scrollValue > sectionThreeValue) {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

In template:

```
.... //scrollValue initialized to this moment
<span ng-bind="getStep(scrollValue)"></span>
....
```

Comment: Any possibility to write inline multiple expression and condition

Comment: You can write what you want in double curly brackets, but it will look ugly:

{{ scrollValue > sectionOneValue ? 1 : (scrollValue > sectionTwoValue ? 2 : (scrollValue > sectionThreeValue ? 3 : 0)) }}